# Squares on monitor that do not go away after restarting pc message in squares is 8x10 and 5x7

Tags: windows-10, display, gpu

While working with PC, (browsing, printing) squares appeared on the monitor that do not refresh.

I restarted (and later shut down and turned on) pc, but squares don't seem to go away. I have a projector connected to PC, however, it is off and switching it on or off does not change anything, also, I have used this setup for a couple of months and this is first.

[image]

When I restart monitor they do the following.

[Inside squares appears text that says '8x10 5x7'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UXZc-WRbGnM)

**What have I done and how do I fix this**?

Comment: What's the make and model of the monitor?

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode? If not, then some installed app is doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I have accidentally pressed the button under the monitor, when plugging in the charger, lol. I did it from behind display then went on with my day, and never associated the frames appearing with it.

I will leave this question and answer to bring me shame forever.